# Creating a reduced set and nested array within an array of objects

Tags: javascript, reduce

I'm trying to wrap my head around transforming an array of "flat" objects, into a condensed but nested version:

```js
const startingArray = [
  { name: 'one', id: 100, thing: 1 },
  { name: 'one', id: 100, thing: 2 },
  { name: 'one', id: 100, thing: 4 },
  { name: 'two', id: 200, thing: 5 }
];

/*
desiredResult = [
  {name: 'one', id:100, things: [
    {thing: 1}, {thing: 2}, {thing:4}
  ]},
  {name: 'two', id:200, things: [
    {thing: 5}
  ]}
]
*/

// THIS DOES NOT WORK
const result = startingArray.reduce((acc, curr) => {
  if (acc.name) {
    acc.things.push(curr.thing)
  }
  return { name: curr.name, id: curr.id, things: [{thing: curr.thing}] };
}, {});
```

What am I not understanding?!

Comment: Object keys must be unique. `{thing: 1, thing: 2, thing:4}` can't happen

Comment: Ah right, I've updated the desired result

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your reduce callback, `acc` is not "each element of the array" (that's what `curr` is) or "the matching element in the results" (you have to determine this yourself), it's the accumulated object being transformed with each call to the function.

That is to say, when you `return { name: curr.name, id: curr.id, things: [{thing: curr.thing}] };`, it sets `acc` to that object for the next iteration, discarding whatever data was contained in it before - `acc.name` will only ever hold the last name iterated over and the results will never accumulate into anything meaningful.

What you want to do is accumulate the results in an array (because it's your desired output), making sure to return that array each iteration:

```js
const startingArray = [
  { name: 'one', id: 100, thing: 1 },
  { name: 'one', id: 100, thing: 2 },
  { name: 'one', id: 100, thing: 4 },
  { name: 'two', id: 200, thing: 5 }
];

const result = startingArray.reduce((acc, curr) => {
  let existing = acc.find(o => o.id == curr.id);
  if(!existing) acc.push(existing = { name: curr.name, id: curr.id, things: [] });
  existing.things.push({thing: curr.thing});
  return acc;
}, []);

console.log(result);
```

Because of your desired result format this involves quite a few `acc.find()` calls, which is expensive - you can get around this in a concise way with this trick, using the first element of the accumulator array as a mapping of ids to references (also featuring ES6 destructuring):

```js
const startingArray = [
  { name: 'one', id: 100, thing: 1 },
  { name: 'one', id: 100, thing: 2 },
  { name: 'one', id: 100, thing: 4 },
  { name: 'two', id: 200, thing: 5 }
];

const result = startingArray.reduce((acc, {name, id, thing}) => {
  if(!acc[0][id])
    acc.push(acc[0][id] = { name, id, things: [] });
  acc[0][id].things.push({thing});
  return acc;
}, [{}]).slice(1); //slice off the mapping as it's no longer needed

console.log(result);
```

Comment: One syntax I don't quite understand  `acc.push(existing = {...})`

Comment: @skube From [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Assignment_Operators) - `The assignment operation evaluates to the assigned value.` So you have the inner part which assigns `existing` to an  object, and that inner expression evaluates also to that object, so you end up pushing the object as well as assigning it. It's just a little bit of fancy shorthand for more concise code

Answer (score 1):

Ok, providing alternative way. Key point is that you accumulate an Object and later take only the values, so get an Array:

```js
const startingArray = [
  { name: 'one', id: 100, thing: 1 },
  { name: 'one', id: 100, thing: 2 },
  { name: 'one', id: 100, thing: 4 },
  { name: 'two', id: 200, thing: 5 }
];

const res = startingArray.reduce((acc, curr) => {
   if (acc[curr.name]) {
     acc[curr.name].things.push({thing: curr.thing})
   } else {
     acc[curr.name] = { 
       name: curr.name,
       id: curr.id,
       things: [{thing: curr.thing}] 
    }
   }
   return acc
 }, {})

 console.log(Object.values(res))
```